# Demonstration of the UCB formula used in Monte-Carlo Tree search

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo

I am really interested in [Monte-Carlo Tree Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search), and its "UCB1" formula :
$$S_i =x_i + C\sqrt{\frac{\ln(t)}{n_i}}$$
$S_i$ is the "Score" of a node $i$, $x_i$ its empirical mean, $C$ a constant, $t$ the total number of simulations, and $n_i$ is the number of simulations of the node $i$ (if I understood correctly).
The term $C\sqrt{\frac{\ln(t)}{n_i}}$ is supposed to represent the "minimization of the regret", or how confident you are in $x_i$ : confidence interval, for example in the case of a [multi-armed bandit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit)
However, I searched and I can't find a mathematical demonstration for the formula of this term.

Can anyone help me ?

edit : I found the  paper of the people who introduced it : https ://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1013689704352.pdf, but I fail to understand the logic behind what THM 1 is saying and the formula above.

Comment: [link to the paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1013689704352.pdf), they don't want more than two links

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is not derived from first principles but wisely proposed and proved to result a bound on regret. See proof 1 in the [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1013689704352.pdf)

Later I found an explanation based on some assumptions on the reward distribution (sub-gaussian), see this [blog](http://banditalgs.com/2016/09/18/the-upper-confidence-bound-algorithm/)